# Creating Local (MAMP) PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, localhost, mamp

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this question.

First let me explain what I am trying to accomplish here...

So i need to create a form, which needs to be run locally on my mac. This form needs to store user details, and email the user upon submission.

I have decided to use MAMP, however i am open to any suggestions here. However it is very important this is done locally. I can easily achieve this by building the form on a live server, however that is not an option.

In order to simplify, lets just assume the there are only 2 fields for the form. Name and Email.

Here is a snippet of the HTML.

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="Please enter your name">

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input name="email" type="email"  placeholder="Please enter your email address here">

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?php


define('DB_NAME', 'test');

define('DB_USER', 'root');

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');



$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('cant use ' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
}


echo 'connected successfuly';


?>
```

When visiting the local host url to this php file, i am not getting a could not connect message etc. I am getting an error 'The localhost page isn’t working'

At this point i would like to mention, I build a lot of Joomla sites locally, so normally there is a sound connection here.

Also worth mentioning. I have created a database in phpMyAdmin, and the table to accommodate the 2 inputs.

Checking the error log for MAMP i get this error;

thrown in /localurl/demo.php on line 10

Which is this line of PHP here...

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Quite new to PHP forms, i would normally just use some Joomla plugin to achieve this on a website.

I know there are similar questions like this on stack overflow. However they have not helped me one bit. I've watched a load of videos and still no closer to getting this piece of work done.

Any help with this will be very much appreciated!

Thanks very much.

EDIT:

Made some slight progress. I changed the SQL Port in MAMP to 3306.

I then ran this command in terminal;

```
ps aux | grep mysql 
lsof -i 
killall -9 mysqld
```

And re started MAMP servers.

Now i am not getting an error stated above 'local host page isn't working'

But i do have a blank white page, and an error log in the php file;

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Why is not saying connected or not connected?

Comment: so wait, you can't even see the localhost page? you should solve that first, all the details about mysql connection are completely irrelevant until you can at least see your page with the form

Comment: Of course i can see the form, sorry i should of been more clear. When i visit the url of the php file (demo.php) or when i submit the form - notice action="demo.php" i get the error.

Comment: is the html page and demo.php same file? You separated the code, but are they actually in one document?

Comment: Nope. they are 2 different files, demo.php and demo-form.php

Comment: I have made some slight progress. See edit.

Comment: what is the PHP version you are using? Just because on PHP7 mysql_* has been completely removed after being deprecated for so long. So your code will not work unless you switch to mysqli_* api or even better to PDO. Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injections!

Comment: MAMP is using PHP version 7.1.0, can you give me any guidence here please? Thank you so much.

Comment: you said you have an error in php file.......what is it?